# Running WF Workflow in REST API

Tags: rest, api, workflow, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to execute WF Workflows in REST API/Web API. I am planning to use "WorkflowApplication" object to run a workflow.   For each request to start a WF, a separate instance of the "WorkflowApplication" object will be used to  run a workflow.  I haven't seen any articles which says I can use WorkFlows in REST API.  Do you see any issues in doing this?.  If yes, what alternatives I have?

Comment: Yes, you can. Is it a good idea? I don't know.  You should create a prototype (it would be relatively trivial to do so) with a workflow that is representative of the high end, complexity-wise, you would expect to run in production, and see what the performance is like.  WF is a relatively mothballed part of the framework.  It won't be removed, I think, but it's not under active improvement.

Comment: As Will mentions, it is possible to spin up a [WorkflowApplication] object within a REST Api method and invoking it from there. Another approach is to spin up a WCF Workflow Application Service, which uses WCF to host the workflow. That might be the better approach if you wish to launch workflows via a web endpoint. WCF does wrap web calls in a SOAP protocol, but that is under the hood a REST Api method anyway.